# Java Servlet/ How to write the logs(log.debug and log.error entries) written in the server console to a separate txt file?

Tags: java, servlets

This is my first java servlet so I would be glad if you can help me and tell me what to do in details :) I can see my program's logs in server console but I need to copy all logs including log.debug and log.error entries to a txt file and later send the txt file via email.

I have to define the directory/file for the logs. I have managed this for a regular java program by adding log4j.xml under src folder so I could set the directory in it, it worked, it is writing logs to a txt file created. But I do not know how to do it for the servlet version of my program. How can I set the directory for logs in the servlet and write logs to a specific txt file?

Answer (score 1):

Use  `log4j` and have a `FileAppender` configured

Answer (score 0):

You could use `log4j` too with servlets. You just have to add your log4j.xml in the folder `YOURWEBAPP/WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: File not found: "C:\IBM\Workspaces\JavaServlet\MyServlet\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.dtd , giving such an error.Plus, the log4j.xml I created in WEB-INF/classes gets dissappeared after I clean/build the app.I tried this before but it did not work, that is why I decided to ask it in here. :/

Comment: And I copied log4j.dtd from prop file to WEB-INF/classes together with log4j.xml, but both of them get dissappeared after I clean/build the app. I can see logs in the console though but I want to copy logs to a txt file.